# Gnome overview search triplicate of the first letter

Tags: xorg, gnome-shell, 21.10

I use Gnome 40, X11, Ubuntu 21.10.
When in overview I press a letter to search I get that letter 3 times.
If I already is in the search bar, no duplicates are created.

Any ideas on what could cause that or how to fix it?

Comment: After a patch of Ubuntu this problem went away.

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04.1, GNOME 42.5, and I'm getting a similar problem. I cannot connect it with anything in particular that can cause it. And it's not always triplicated, sometimes the letter is quadruplicated. I'm not using suspend (because it causes other problems like not working wifi) so Ubuntu is always booted in fresh state.

Answer (score 3):

I don't really have a fix for you, but I have the same issue (sometimes it's more than 3 of that letter) and for me it only happens after a suspend, not off a fresh boot. After a suspend, refreshing the session (Alt+F2 > r > Enter) also "fixes" it.

I also think it might have to do with Dash to Dock. But I'm not sure of that just yet.

Comment: I tested without any extensions enabled, did not make a difference at that point. I now have Dash to dock without problems... lets see if it comes back. :)

Comment: Same issue in Ubuntu 22.04 (Xorg session), after each suspend an additional character is added. The trick to refresh the session is fixing it, thanks!

Comment: I believe this issue started for me either when I installed extensions or dash-to-dock.   Hope there's a more permanent fix soon!