# Ubuntu 22.04 GNOME Search Not Working Correctly

Tags: gnome, keyboard, search

I am pretty new to Ubuntu and Linux in general. About a week ago I installed a theme for Ubuntu (WhiteSur if it matters). After I installed the theme, there is a bug with my GNOME search bar (when you press the SUPER key and start writing). Whenever I type a letter after pressing the SUPER key, the letter is written twice into the search (and it also is registered as if I typed the letter twice), no matter which letter (so it should be nothing with my keyboard). However, if I first click into the search bar, just one letter is registered.

Any ideas on how to fix it? It is kind of annoying having to delete a letter everytime I want to search for an application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/4651) that occurs even without extensions (on Wayland) and that has not yet been resolved. It seems sometimes to be related to/caused by dash-to-dock, so if you are using that extension or it is part of the theme you installed, try disabling it and see if that fixes the issue. You will have to restart the Gnome session (log out and back in again) after disabling dash-to-dock in order to restore normal functionality. You can also try switching from Wayland to Xorg or vice-versa, and seeing if that changes anything. Gnome developers are working on the issue, and hopefully it gets fixed eventually!

Comment: Thank you, dash-to-dock caused this issue for me. I suspected the theme but I directly installed dash-to-dock after installing the theme.

I disabled dash-to-dock and after logging in again everything works correctly again.

Answer (score 3):

If the theme is causing the problem, then uninstall the theme.

There's no guarantee that any third party "eye candy" is going to work with your version of Ubuntu. A lot of the themes out in the wild are either ancient, unmaintained, or buggy.

GNOME has very few customization options without being forced to install 3rd party software that may or may not contain bugs. This is a "feature" of GNOME that it lacks a lot of bells and whistles so that it is easier to use. If this isn't what you want, there are over half a dozen [official Ubuntu "flavours"](https://ubuntu.com/desktop/flavours) with different desktop environments providing users with varying levels of user customization options.

Any customization options that are part of the stock options in your desktop environment are rigorously tested and should be bug free. If you are having problems with any officially supported settings, please file a bug report.

However, if your problem is a bug with third party software, you should discontinue its use. You can file a bug report to the maintainers, if there are any.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! As already commented on the other answer, the "dash-to-dock" extensions actually caused this issue for me. I installed it directly after installing the theme and I have not thought that the extension could cause the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Happening to me as well. I don't have "dash to dock" so it has to be something else. In my case it happens after each suspend. The solution, taken from [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1371503/823631), is to "refresh the session", whatever that means. For doing that:

1. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>.
2. On the popup box, write `r`.
3. Hit enter.
4. Wait a few seconds.

That fixes this issue for me.